# Arduino MotorShield code running but not motors

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, arduino-motor-shield

I have a motor shield V2 on my Arduino, i compile the codes just fine and i'm trying to just run the example dc motor test. The code compiles the serial is printing out the "tick tock ...." but the motors are not running. They ran once before on my mac though.

Using a 9v battery to power a basic Dc motor.

I'm using the right ports on pc. Same exact port for motor as the code tells. I'm not sure where i am wrong. TYIA

[image]
[image]

Comment: We are not sitting beside you and we can't look at your code over your shoulder... You know that right?
You must post your code using the appropriate formatting and describe or draw a diagram of your wiring: pictures are not helping.

How are you powering the shield?
What type of motor are you trying to drive? You spoke of `motors` (plural) but I believe you have only one motor connected.

Comment: Neither can we see where those wires go. This isn't Bladerunner.

Comment: My code has no errors and compiles fine. It also did work before. I'm just wondering if there is something wrong with my set up that i'm not noticing or if there are PC specific differences, since this did run fine on my mac. I Will add photos of what the wires go to.

Comment: Do i need to provide more descriptions? sorry about earlier =(

Comment: Your mac has been blessed by fairy dust and is using its supernatural powers to force your midichlorians spin the motor...

Option 1: battery voltage is not enough to spin the motor
Option 2: battery is wired the other way around
Option 3: one of those taped connections has simply got lose and circuit is open
Option 4: motor is wired the other way around
Option 5: motor is dead
Option 6: shield is dead
Option 7: arduino is dead
Option 8: the universe is playing against you
Option 9: I can keep going, the number of things you could have done wrong is probably endless

Comment: lmaooooo so helpful. Nah the motor runs more than fine when connected straight to the battery. So battery and dc motor are not dead. The battery is wired right other wise the LED would just not even go on. The taped connections are also not lose, because again the LED light would not turn on. Motor wired around or not would only change the direction of rotation and i did switch them previously just in case. Arduino is not dead as it runs other stuff just fine. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the pins connecting the shield to the Arduino are quite loose and didn't "touch" the Arduino.

Comment: That was option 42 on my list of possible failures

Comment: I had that on one Arduino once - the actual header sockets were inferior quality and some contacts didn't have the springiness they should have. I resorted to replacing all the sockets on the board. I think Arduino had a bad batch at one point in their history, since I haven't had the issue since with any other Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a 9v battery to power a basic Dc motor.

Don't do that.  These were designed for early transistorized radios, which needed a moderately high voltage but very low current.

There are very few motors with suitable low-current coil characteristics to be driven by such a battery.  Others might work at best briefly before killing the battery.

If you need around 9 volts for a motor project, you should probably use 6 or so AA cells.